# SA1600 too expansive

Tags: visual-studio, stylecop

At my job our internal coding standards say that we only want XML documentation on methods. Unfortunately, whenever I run StyleCop, I get SA1600 warnings that say I need documentation for things like the class, properties, fields, etc. I know that you can somewhat limit the scope of SA1600 in StyleCop settings, but is there a way to take this further so that I only get StyleCop SA1600 violations for methods?

Alternatively, is there a way I can limit an SA1600 supression to apply to only a class documentation header, but not to its contents? (i.e. I want to supress the warning on `Class helloWorld`, but I still want the warnings to appear for all of the methods in that class.)